# AngularJS: DOM manipulation once view is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, timeout, angularjs-ng-repeat

Apologies for the long post - I hope it doesn't put too many people off. What I have is working, but I'm just not sure if it's the "correct" way of doing things, so I'm just looking for some advice.

I have a page where I'm using the window size to calculate where to position a dynamic number of elements. These elements are spaced out according to how big the window is, and then I'm using the Canvas element to draw lines connecting each element to a central element.

The problem I have is knowing when all elements have been created and are now ready for resizing and positioning.

My HTML is something like this:

```
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel_content">
            <div class="input_mapping" ng-repeat="input in inputs" mapping-resize>
                {{input.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel_content">
            <div class="central_mapping">
                {{mapping.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel_content">
            <div class="output_mapping" ng-repeat="output in outputs" mapping-resize>
                {{output.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm using the directive, mapping-resize, to resize everything but this runs on each ng-repeat. Really, I only want to run it once, once all the child elements are created but if I put the directive on the parent div (panel_content), it isn't aware of the child elements at the point the directive runs and so doesn't reposition them.

My directive is currently this:

```
app.directive('mappingResize', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return function(scope, elem, attrs) {

        if(scope.$last) {
            $timeout(function() {
                positionElements();
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

positionElements() is, as it suggests, where all my code is for positioning elements once they've been created. It's working fine, although it could probably be done in a more "angular way" (it's just a standard JS function which is reliant on full-blown jQuery).

In the directive, I'm using the $last property so I only call positionElements() if it's the last element in the ng-repeat, as I need to know about all of them in order to position them correctly. I'm also using $timeout so the code is queued to run after the page is rendered.

My question is, is this the best I can do?

At the moment, I'm calling positionElements() twice - once for the input mappings ng-repeat, and once for the output mappings. Really, I just need to call it once (and only once) when all mapping elements have been created.
It also doesn't feel very nice to be using $timeout and $last - it feels like there would be some event that tells me that the view has been created, but everything I've found has been a dead end.

Anyway, suggestions or advice on the above would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $timeout and move your directive at the end of your page:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = { items: [1,2,3,4,5] };
});

app.directive('directive', function () {
  return {
    link : function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      console.log(attrs.index);
    }
  }
});

app.directive('lastDirective', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    link : function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      $timeout(function () {
        // position elements here
        console.log(attrs.index);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in model.items" directive index="1"></div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in model.items" directive index="2"></div>
    <div last-directive index="3"></div>
  </body>
```

open console to see directive execution order

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y1KIGAa7hDjY9STlmPm2?p=preview